# Pandas dataframe of sums from another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sum

I have a pandas dataframe. I want to make another dataframe, which columns will be the sums of selected columns from first frame.

For example in first dataframe I have columns named `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'` and `'D'`. New columns are `'X'` and `'Y'` and `'X'` has to be them sum of `'A'`,`'B'` and `'C'` and `'Y'` contains only `'D'`. "Mapping" may be saved in dictionary: `{'X': ['A', 'B', 'C'], Y: ['D']}`, but it does not necessarily need to be.

Shall I initialize the empty data frame with keys `'X'` and `'Y'` and then add columns or is there a quicker way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just directly initialize the DataFrame with the data already in it:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X': df[['A', 'B', 'C']].sum(axis=1), 'Y': df['D']})
```

Or you can build it column by column:

```
df2 = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].sum(axis=1).to_frame(name='X')
df2['Y'] = df['D']
```

For the first column, you'll need to call `to_frame` with `name` as your desired column name.  Otherwise, `df2` will be a Series instead of a DataFrame and you'll have trouble adding columns.  After the the initial column, you can just assign columns as usual.

Sample input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[3,1,4],'B':[1,5,9],'C':[2,6,5],'D':[3,5,8]})

   A  B  C  D
0  3  1  2  3
1  1  5  6  5
2  4  9  5  8
```

Sample Output (for either method):

```
    X  Y
0   6  3
1  12  5
2  18  8
```